# How can I combine the PTV Developer vector map with satellite images using MapBox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, ptv-developer

I want to combine the PTV Developer vector map with satellite images creating a hybrid view. How can I achieve this? Is this possible using the existing MapBox [sample](https://developer.myptv.com/Documentation/Vector%20Maps%20API/Code%20Samples/Creating%20a%20map%20app.htm) or do I have to use a different client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using the given MapBox sample. The trick is to add an additional layer injecting the satellite tiles on top of the background just below the railway lines like so:

```
[...]

// inject satellite tiles
map.once('style.load', (ev) => {
      map.addSource('satellite-tiles', {
"type": "raster",
"tiles": [
  https://api.myptv.com/rastermaps/v1/satellite-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}
],
"tileSize": 256,
"minzoom": 0,
"maxzoom": 20
});

map.addLayer({
"id": "satellite-tiles",
"type": "raster",
"source": "satellite-tiles"
}, 'BKG_RailwayLinear');
});

[...]
```

Be sure to insert the above snippet just below the map initialization. You can find a full sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/oliverheilig/9vzeutkj/.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a predefined hybrid-style available:

https://vectormaps-resources.myptv.com/styles/latest/hybrid.json

This should make it much easier. You can get more infos in the [tutorial](https://developer.myptv.com/en/resources/tutorials/map-rendering/vector-map-satellite).